# How to install ss7MAPer on ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa

Tags: rebar3, ss7

I have installed ss7MAPer on my ubuntu 20.04 ; I have followed all the steps to compile the program but when I reached the final step which is running this command:

```
./rebar3 shell
```

it fail to run!
The output is :

```
Failed to read osmoss7_link_m3ua file
```

I tried many time to fix this issue but I can't. So who can help me to fkx it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Which version of ss7MAPer are you trying to install and from which repository? Can you give a link to the instructions you are following? Can you provide the full output?

Comment: Hello Vasil this is the link:

Comment: https://github.com/ernw/ss7MAPer/issues/34

Comment: I don't the version yet because but the repo is ernw

Comment: Why do you use `rebar3` and not `rebar`? What happens when you execute `rebar shell` as described in the [Readme.md](https://github.com/ernw/ss7MAPer/blob/master/README.md#running-a-source-build)?

Comment: There are some erl files which are not available in rebar escript folder!

Comment: Which files are missing? You can edit your question and add the additional info. Also if you found a solution you can post an answer to your own question.